# angular - how to change inputfield to readonly with a switch

Tags: angular, input, switch-statement, angular8, readonly

I'm working on a project where I have an input field. Below this input field, there is a switch, if the switch is disabled, the input field is `readonly`.

Currently, I have the following solution, which does the job but is not nice. (If I use the switch, the input field disparat for some seconds):

**app.component.html**

```
<input *ngIf="isReadonly" readonly type="text"[formControl]="title">
<input *ngIf="!isReadonly" type="text" [formControl]="title">

<div class="switch form-switch" role="switch">
  <input type='checkbox' id='switch' (click)="switch()">
  <label for='title_switch'>{{'CUSTOM_TITLE_SWITCH'|translate}}</label>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
isReadonly = true

switch() {
 this.isReadonly = !this.isReadonly
}
```

As I said, this solution works but it's not nice. Does anyone have a better idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to bind the `readonly` attribute?

```
<input [readonly]="isReadonly" type="text" [formControl]="title">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this.
Here is one of them using a `ngModel` binding on your `checkbox`. You can use binding too on the `readonly` property (no need to use a `*ngIf` to toggle the input).

Html:

```
<input [readonly]="isReadonly" type="text" value="Text example">

<div class="switch form-switch" role="switch">
  <input type='checkbox' id='switch' [(ngModel)]="isReadonly">
  <label for='title_switch'>Switch</label>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public isReadonly: boolean = true;
}
```

Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabcjw

If you are using you inputs inside a `formGroup` simply add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` on your `checkbox` (as explained here: [Use of [(ngModel)] within FormGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549426/use-of-ngmodel-within-formgroup)):

```
<div class="switch form-switch" role="switch">
  <input type='checkbox' id='switch' [(ngModel)]="isReadonly" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <label for='title_switch'>Switch</label>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I'll get this error:`ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive.`

Comment: Yes it's because you use `formGroup`. You can add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549426/use-of-ngmodel-within-formgroup